# How do you get back the Designer window in QT?

Tags: qt

I went into Views and disabled the Designer window (the window where you place the widgets) and now I can't get it back. The Designer window is completely gone from the Views tab and clicking Views->Reset to default layout does not bring the window back. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project with `.ui` or `.xml` files, and double click on it. It will open the Designer view!